# Almost sure convergence of $L^p$ convergent series

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere

I am wondering if my following reasoning is correct.

I have a series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ that converges in $L^p(\Omega)$ to some $X$. $L^p$ convergence implies a.e. convergence of a subsequence, hence $\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}X_i$ converges almost everywhere to $X$ for some increasing $(n_k)_k$. But by definition the limit of this subsequence is the same as $\sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i$, so this series also converges a.e. to $X$.

Comment: The problem is that your series may not even converge almost everywhere (we are only given that it converges in $L^p$). So in general that is not correct.

Comment: Thank you. See my comment on Idontgetit's answer for what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2):

The limit in $L^p$ will coincide with the almost-everywhere-limit of the subsequence.
However, this does not imply that the whole sequence converges almost everywhere.

Classical counterexample:
Write $Y_k:=\sum_{i=1}^k X_i$.
Let $\{Y_k\}$ be the sequence of indicator functions
$$\chi_{[0,1/2]},\chi_{[1/2,1]},\chi_{[0,1/4]},\chi_{[1/4,1/2]},\dots$$
This sequence converges in $L^p([0,1])$ to $0$.
It has an almost everywhere convergent subsequence:
$$\chi_{[0,1/2]},\chi_{[0,1/4]},\chi_{[0,1/8]},\dots$$
Yet, it converges nowhere.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of this problem and the example you gave. Somehow I had convinced myself that dealing with a series instead of a sequence solved this problem, since somehow "all terms" were included in the subsequence too when dealing with a series. However as you pointed out we can of course write any sequence as a series and vice versa.